# varchar to numeric in PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql

I have a shell script in Linux that downloads data from a WFS and writes it into a table in PostgreSQL.

The workflow:

- Initiate by cronjob
- Download data from WFS and stored locally as shapefile
- Table in PostgreSQL from previous day is deleted
- Table in postgresql from last day is renamed as previous day
- Downloaded data is uploaded in postgresql using shp2pgsql
- Table is changed using SQL script into form I want.

The problem:

- In the original WFS, all the datatypes in all columns are set as a string
- The comma is used as decimal seperator.
- QGIS gives me the "can't convert to double" error when I try to use the data in a expressionbuilder or data-defined rule.

What I would like:

- During import I want to write the data to the PostgreSQL table as the correct datatype, with a . as the decimal separator.

I have tried:

- Added lines in the SQL script to make a new column with the correct datatype and using
  UPDATE table_name SET new_column = old_column; without succes. Got a can't write varchar to numeric.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried : `UPDATE table_name SET new_column = replace(old_column, ',', '.');`. And even if you import a shapefile in PostgreSQL (I think it has PostGIS as spatial extension), the problem and question is not about spatial or geometry, so I vote to close because this question is about DB or general IT.

Comment: If you have to massage the data anyway, you really shouldn't DROP the served table, and should instead TRUCATE/INSERT or UPDATE in to reflect the new data ***after*** all the other work is done

Comment: ...and a good workflow here could be to a) have a partitioned table for which you add a new partition in cron and b) an import *View* with an `INSTSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger to transform the data prior to inserting. You could easily drop partitions if needed, even by cron schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in an alter table statement:

```
alter table your_table alter column decimal_column type double precision using replace(decimal_column, ',', '.')::double precision;
```

Or do as J. Monticolo suggested and just update the column:

```
update your_table set decimal_column = replace(decimal_column, ',', '.');
```